# Downloading, decompressing and inserting data into an SQLite database

Tags: java, performance, android, sqlite

I have implemented a Service, which executes three operations, in the following order:

1. Downloading a compressed (.zip) CSV file
2. Decompress the CSV file
3. Reading the CSV file and inserting the data into a SQLite database

I'm more or less pleased with the performance of (1) and (2), but (3) is taking quite some time. Depending on which unit I debug on, and the size of the CSV file, it takes 45-120 seconds. I'd like this part to be a bit faster.

As stated, the first and second operations are currently fine in the aspect of performance, but I will add the code and appreciate any input that would lead to an increased performance. However, focus is on (3), since it's the slowest as of now.

**(1) Downloading and (2) Decompressing**

Below is the code that defines the AsyncTask which downloads and decompresses the CSV file. It's started from a service, and is provided with a URL which points to the location of the file. Also provided is the helper class which handles the decompress logic.

```
private class DownloadSaidAndDoneDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();           
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            int lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 10 * 1024);

            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Riksdagskollen");
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                folder.mkdir();
            }

            // Output stream to write file in SD card
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Riksdagskollen/Sagtochgjort.zip");
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // Publish the progress which triggers onProgressUpdate method
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                // Write data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);

            }
            // Flush output
            output.flush();
            // Close streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

            //Unzip
            String zipFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Riksdagskollen/Sagtochgjort.zip";
            String unzipLocation = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Riksdagskollen/";
            Decompress d = new Decompress(zipFile, unzipLocation);
            d.unzip();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        //Update progressbar
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        downloadSaidAndDoneDataTask = null;
        //Initiate database insert when download and decompress are done
        insertCsvDataIntoDatabase();
    }
}
```

**Decompress.java**

```
public class Decompress {
    private String _zipFile;
    private String _location;

    public Decompress(String zipFile, String location) {
        _zipFile = zipFile;
        _location = location;

        hanldeDirectory("");
    }

    public void unzip() {

        try {
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(_zipFile);
            ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(inputStream);
            ZipEntry zEntry = null;
            while ((zEntry = zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                Log.d("Unzip", "Unzipping " + zEntry.getName() + " at "
                        + _location);

                if (zEntry.isDirectory()) {
                    hanldeDirectory(zEntry.getName());
                } else {
                    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(
                            this._location + "/" + zEntry.getName());
                    BufferedOutputStream bufout = new BufferedOutputStream(fout);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int read = 0;
                    while ((read = zipStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        bufout.write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }

                    zipStream.closeEntry();
                    bufout.close();
                    fout.close();
                }
            }
            zipStream.close();
            Log.d("Unzip", "Unzipping complete. path :  " + _location);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Unzip", "Unzipping failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void hanldeDirectory(String dir) {
        File f = new File(this._location + dir);
        if (!f.isDirectory()) {
            f.mkdirs();
        }
    }
}
```

**(3) Inserting**

This operation is my main concern. I've managed to reduce the execution time from 25 minutes to 1-2 minutes by handling the inserts as a single transaction. If possible, I'd like it to be even faster.

```
private class InsertSaidAndDoneDataIntoDataBase extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String csvFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Riksdagskollen/Sagtochgjort.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        BufferedReader brCount = null;
        String line;
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";
        long total = 0;

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            brCount = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            dataSource.open();
            dataSource.beginTransaction();

            long lenghtOfFile = 0;
            while (brCount.readLine() != null) {
                lenghtOfFile++;
            }

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && !canceledDatabaseTransaction) {
                total++;

                String[] data = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                String personId = data[0];
                String documentType = data[4];
                String subType = data[5];
                String session = data[6];
                String documentId = data[7];
                String term = data[8];
                String authority = data[9];
                String date = data[10];
                String speaker = data[11];
                String speakerTime = data[15];
                String numOfChars = data[16];
                String personActivities = data[17];
                dataSource.createSaidAndDoneEntry(personId, documentType, subType, session, documentId, term, authority, date,
                        speaker, speakerTime, numOfChars, personActivities);

                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

            }
            dataSource.setTransactionSuccessful();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                dataSource.endTransaction();
                dataSource.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (brCount != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        //Update progress dialog
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);           
        insertSaidAndDoneDataIntoDataBase = null;
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Below is the code for the `createSaidAndDoneEntry` method. `database` is the reference from `getReadableDatabase()` which I call in a separate method prior to any database calls.

```
public long createSaidAndDoneEntry(String personId, String documentType, String subType,
                                   String session, String documentId, String term,
                                   String authority, String date, String speaker,
                                   String speakerTime, String numberOfChars,
                                   String personActivities) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_SAIDANDDONE_PERSON_ID, personId);
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_SAIDANDDONE_DOCUMENT_TYPE, documentType);
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_SAIDANDDONE_SUB_TYPE, subType);
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_SAIDANDDONE_SESSION, session);
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_SAIDANDDONE_DOCUMENT_ID, documentId);
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_SAIDANDDONE_TERM, term);
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_SAIDANDDONE_AUTHORITY, authority);
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_SAIDANDDONE_DATE, date);
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_SAIDANDDONE_SPEAKER, speaker);
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_SAIDANDDONE_SPEAKER_TIME, speakerTime);
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_SAIDANDDONE_NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS, numberOfChars);
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_SAIDANDDONE_PERSON_ACTIVITIES, personActivities);

    return database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME_SAIDANDDONE, null, values);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview, Marcus. This is a well written first post! I hope you get some fine answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you could save quite some time by making the operations overlap: Feed the download stream into the `ZipInputStream` and feed the output into the database. The timing could be something like `max(a, b, c)` instead of `a+b+c`, but it could easily lead to a messy code, so let's forget it for now.

I'll only look at the third part, i.e., `InsertSaidAndDoneDataIntoDataBase`.

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}
```

This does nothing, so leave it out.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String csvFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Riksdagskollen/Sagtochgjort.csv";
```

The filename surely should be a constant. Moreover, during the decompression you may want to look if such an entry exists.

```
BufferedReader br = null;
BufferedReader brCount = null;
String line;
String cvsSplitBy = ",";
```

The first two have to be declared outside of the try-finally block, but the latter two don't. Always minimize the scope.

Also consider something smarter than classical try-finally, maybe Lombok's [@Cleanup](http://projectlombok.org/features/Cleanup.html) or Guava's [Closer](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Closer.html).

I'd also use a single `BufferedReader` variable only. After counting the
lines, I'd close it and reassign a new `BufferedReader` to the variable. Re-reading a file is pretty wasteful, but I guess, you can't simply read it all into memory (as `ArrayList<String>`)?

```
long lenghtOfFile = 0;
```

But it's not the file length.

```
dataSource.createSaidAndDoneEntry
```

I'm afraid, this is the time-consuming part. And you're keeping the `dataSource` code secret.

Some databases can read CSV directly, I'd check this first. Otherwise, I'm not sure about Android, but normally you should

- use a `PreparedStatement`
- consider [using `addBatch`](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/javaentnut_2/index3.html?page=2).

Comment: Hi @maaartinus, thank you for your valuable input. I've added the code for `dataSource.createSaidAndDoneEntry`. I'll also have a look at your suggestions regarding PreparedStatement and addBatch. In the meantime, please have a look at my edit. Thanks.